# Thermal vibration of bonds

Tags: thermodynamics, bond

So, the characteristic frequency of thermal motion is around 7E12 Hz at room temperature (300K), but from that information how can we conclude that the bonds are hard; they don't vibrate !!

Comment: Thermal energy does not affect the frequency of bond vibration;  all bonds vibrate with zero-point energy as well as at higher energy. Vibrational frequencies are particular to the type of molecule and depend on the exact nature of the interaction forming the chemical bonds; this is called the potential energy profile (or surface). Thermal energy just populates more energy levels and so more transitions are seen in infra-red or Raman spectroscopy which are the usual experimental techniques used to measure molecular bond vibration frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

The bond energy is related to which kind of molecules are involved in the bond itself (their polarity,...). all the molecular bonds undergo some kind of vibration (they can bend, stretch, rock,...) which peculiar frequency varies according to the type of bond and molecules involved.